# Adding to a data that's already in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to update a data in the database where the number that I will be submitting will be added to what's the number on the database. Example the number that was on the database was 15 and the number that I will be submitting is 5. What I want to happen was update the number on the database with the sum of 15 and 5. How should I do it? This is an example of my code.

PHP:

```
 include("../../connection.php");

   if(ISSET($_POST['update'])){

$id = $_POST['id'];
$new_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];




mysqli_query($connections, "UPDATE inv_tbl SET inhouse = '$new_quantity + $in' WHERE id = '$id'");

 addLog($connections,"Added a stock");
 header("location: ../stocks.php");
```

}

HTML:

```
            $result = mysqli_query($connections, "SELECT * FROM inv_tbl WHERE itemtype = 'Slim' OR itemtype='Round'");
            if ($result) {
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $id = $row['id'];
                $item = $row['itemtype'];
                $in = $row['inhouse'];
                $out = $row['outhouse'];
                $damaged = $row['dmg'];
                $date = $row['updated_at'];

                echo ' <tr>
                <td> '.$item.' </td>
                <td> '.$in.' </td>
                <td> '.$out.' </td>
                <td> '.$damaged.' </td>';
             
                echo '<td>
                <a> 
                <button button class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" type="button" data-bs-target="#update'.$id.'" style="margin: 3px; font-size: 13px; padding: 3px 5px; min-width: 50px;">Add</button></a></td>
                </tr>

                <div class="modal fade" id="update'.$id.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <form method="POST" class="pt-3" action="stocks/update-query.php">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-white">
                <h5 class="modal-title "><strong>Add slim gallon</strong></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'"/>
                <label for="item" class="text-black"><strong>Item</strong></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="item" value="'.$item.'" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="quantity" class="text-black"><strong>Inside warehouse quantity:</strong></label>
                <input class="form-control" min="0" type="number" name="quantity">
                </div>
                </div>

                </div>    
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button name="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Add</button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>';

              } 

            }
```

Comment: *How should I do it?* `UPDATE table SET column = column + {value to add} WHERE id = {id to be updated} ;`. WHERE must define only the row(s) to be updated.

Comment: `"UPDATE inv_tbl SET inhouse = inhouse + " . intval($new_quantity) . " WHERE id = " . intval($id)`

Comment: Learn about prepared statements! Your code has major security problems. Where do people still teach writing SQL queries like this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, "Your code may has major security problems" like SQL Injections...

I recommend using php prepared statements for database queries like insert or updates. [Check this out](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Your php code will be something like :

```php
include("../../connection.php");
if(ISSET($_POST['update'])){
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $quantity_to_add = $_POST['quantity'];

   // Creating the SQL Statement with "?" sign for parameters 
   $statement = $connections->prepare("UPDATE inv_tbl SET inhouse = (inhouse + ? ) WHERE id = ?");
   // Binding Parameters to local variables
   $statement->bind_param("ii", $quantity_to_add, $id); // assuming that all parameters are integer "ii" : i for integer
   // Executing the statement
   $statement->execute();

   addLog($connections,"Added a stock");
   header("location: ../stocks.php");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'm actually getting a lot of this comments but it's the first time someone actually showed me how. I'm afraid of getting embarassed if I ask how to do it. I'm just new in coding and I'm just applying what my teachers only taught me, I don't even have enough time to study and research since I'm rushing this project.